# Pandas: Applying function f(c1, c2) to all pairwise combinations of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to apply an arbitrary function to each pair of columns in a pandas DataFrame in a fast and neat manner. Generally, the return value is a scalar in which case I would like the result to be a new dataframe analogous to what df.corr() returns. Syntactic convenience is usually a higher priority than computation speed.

With some function `f`, I would like a dataframe as in

```
          a                      b
  ----------------------------------------
a | f(df["a"], df["a"])  f(df["a"], df["b"])
b | f(df["b"], df["a"])  f(df["b"], df["b"])
```

**Ex:** (the actual f is arbitrary)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": range(4), "b": range(1, 5)})
df
>>>
 a  b 
------
 0  1 
 1  2 
 2  3 
 3  4 

def f(c1, c2):
    return max(min(c1), min(c2))
```

Wished result:

```
     a    b
   --------
a | 0     1
b | 1     1
```

Comment: iterating over columns isn't an option?

Comment: @Valentino Overall I guess it does, but I was hoping for a more pandorable way of doing it, perhaps even with built-in pandas functions that directly return a dataframe. If nothing else is suggested, I will settle for that.

Comment: @PabloC Preferably not. As said in my previous comment, I wish(ed) for a "onliner native pandas"-way of doing it. Just seems like a quite common action.

Comment: I honestly am not aware of any built-in pandas function which applies an arbitrary function pairwise to the column of a dataframe, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a way of doing it but it's a little bit tricky and I definitely wouldn't recommend it. Anyway, you can use [`pandas.DataFrame.corrwith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corrwith.html#pandas.DataFrame.corrwith) and change the method parameter by your function:

```
result = [df.corrwith(df[col], method=f) for col in df]
result_df = pd.DataFrame(result, index = df.columns)
```

As I said before, I wouldn't recommend this, instead, I'd do something like:

```
result_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = df.columns, index = df.columns)

for col1 in df:
    for col2 in df:
        result_df[col1][col2] = f(df[col1],df[col2])
```

Which I think is really clear. In both cases printing `result_df` gives you:

```
   a  b
a  0  1
b  1  1
```

By the way, it's not possible to use [`pandas.DataFrame.corr`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) for doing this because the returned dataframe will have only 1s along the diagonal by following the heuristic "the correlation of x with x is always 1".

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way is to use `df.apply` to get output in a long dataframe with multi index columns.

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

data = [
    {"int": 0, "float": 0.0, "string": "A"},
    {"int": 1, "float": 1.0, "string": "B"},
    {"int": 2, "float": 2.0, "string": "C"},
    {"int": 3, "float": 3.0, "string": "D"},
    {"int": 4, "float": 4.0, "string": "E"},
    {"int": 5, "float": 5.0, "string": "F"},
    {"int": 6, "float": 6.0, "string": "G"},
    {"int": 7, "float": 7.0, "string": "H"},
    {"int": 8, "float": 8.0, "string": "I"},
    {"int": 9, "float": 9.0, "string": "J"},
]


def f(a, b):
    return "{};{}".format(a, b)


df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
col_pairs = list(itertools.product(df.columns, repeat=2))

product_df = df.apply(
    lambda row: [f(row[c1], row[c2]) for c1, c2 in col_pairs],
    axis=1,
    result_type="expand",
)
product_df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(col_pairs)
product_df

   int                float                 string              
   int  float string    int    float string    int  float string
0  0;0  0;0.0    0;A  0.0;0  0.0;0.0  0.0;A    A;0  A;0.0    A;A
1  1;1  1;1.0    1;B  1.0;1  1.0;1.0  1.0;B    B;1  B;1.0    B;B
2  2;2  2;2.0    2;C  2.0;2  2.0;2.0  2.0;C    C;2  C;2.0    C;C
3  3;3  3;3.0    3;D  3.0;3  3.0;3.0  3.0;D    D;3  D;3.0    D;D
4  4;4  4;4.0    4;E  4.0;4  4.0;4.0  4.0;E    E;4  E;4.0    E;E
5  5;5  5;5.0    5;F  5.0;5  5.0;5.0  5.0;F    F;5  F;5.0    F;F
6  6;6  6;6.0    6;G  6.0;6  6.0;6.0  6.0;G    G;6  G;6.0    G;G
7  7;7  7;7.0    7;H  7.0;7  7.0;7.0  7.0;H    H;7  H;7.0    H;H
8  8;8  8;8.0    8;I  8.0;8  8.0;8.0  8.0;I    I;8  I;8.0    I;I
9  9;9  9;9.0    9;J  9.0;9  9.0;9.0  9.0;J    J;9  J;9.0    J;J
```